# Drupal7 Filter visible webforms based on user organization

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

We have a Drupal 7 site.

We have a 'User X' that selected what organization they belong to when they registered;organization field. But note, this is not a role - it's just like they selected what company name they belong to.

We have Webforms assigned to different organizations (again, company, not role) by a data value in one of the form's fields; organization field. A 'User Y' assigns this data value to the webform.

We need to filter what webforms 'User X' can see, by organization field.

The filter will be the organization 'User X' selected when registering, compared to the entered data in the organization field in the webform by 'User Y'.

How do I make this filter work? How do I filter what Webforms 'User X' can see?

Comment: The simple answer would be to make Organizations into Roles.  Then each Webform can have perms based on Role.

Comment: The 'Org' is in a drop down on the form for 'User Y' to set. How can you put a role into a dropdown to select from if the user has no access to that role because of their permission level? 'User Y' will not have access to 'Role 5', for example, and thus can not see it in the list, no?

Comment: Right, the by default Drupal is not very granular in its Permissions on Permissions.  Granting people the right to manage their own Role would give them access to all Permissions.  However there is a light weight module called 'Role Delegation' that allows you to grant access for people to change or assign Roles without giving them the full Permissions.  You can make a rule that people in one organization are allowed to assign some roles but not others.  Sorry if I am not understanding your question.  I know I am sorta offering an alternative suggestion rather than the exact answer.

Comment: It's not permissions on permissions. Org, in this case is like 'company name', so it's just our nomenclature that is confusing the issue a bit. So I just want to filter which webforms you can see by matching the assigned company name to the viewer's company name. I'll update the OP

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to write a hook_menu access_callback for each form that checks to see if the user is in the particular organization. It would be helpful to you if there was some naming convention that allowed you to use the same menu hook for all the forms like:

```
$form_id = 'form_org_1'
```

and

```
$user->org = 'org_1'
```

but that's probably not the case. Hopefully there aren't a lot of forms/orgs.